How to set an html date picker max date to equal today
I have a situation where the user should only enter dates before today.

What is the easiest way to do this please?

You have to use js as well, here is an example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Date Picker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="datePicker">Select a date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="datePicker" max="" />
    
        <script>
            // Get today's date
            const today = new Date();
            const formattedDate = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];
            
            // Set the max attribute
            document.getElementById('datePicker').setAttribute('max', formattedDate);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>

